# Не пойму, почему не работает библиотека <cstdlib>

Tags: c++

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>


    int main()
    {
        int N, i;
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("Vvedite kol-vo: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int *a = new int[N];
        printf("Vvedite massiv: ");
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", a[i]);
            a[i] = rand() % 70 + (-20);
        }
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            printf("a[%d]=%d \n", i, a[i]);
        }
        getch();
    }
```

Ошибка при компиляции:

```
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Вы пробовали прогонять под дебаггером? На какой строке вылет происходит?

Comment: Во-первых, это явно С++, а не С. Во-вторых, в <cstdlib> функции - в пространстве имен `std`, а вы его нигде не указываете... Это если таки ошибка при **компиляции**.

Comment: в С индексация массивов начинается с 0, вы начинаете обход почему-то с 1.

Comment: Память под буфер выделяется, но не освобождается надлежащим образом - `delete [] a;`

Answer (score 4):

Если ошибка при **выполнении**, а не при компиляции - то

```
scanf("%d", a[i]);
```

надо заменить на

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

А вообще - зачем вы считываете элементы массива, если тут же их перезаписываете - непонятно...

Про *огрехи*, не влияющие на работу программы, вам уже написали (цикл не с 0, нет освобождения памяти).